# W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I get the warning messages below when I run `sudo apt-get update`:

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_NG) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_NG) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_NG) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_NG) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
```

### What I have tried

- I checked the sources.list file and couldn't find the entries that are in the warning
- I also checked sources.list.d directory, and the directory is empty
- 

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

```
sudo mv sources.list.d/ sources.list.d.backup/
sudo mv sources.list sources.list.backup
```

```
sudo apt-get clean all
```

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

I also want to note that I upgraded my OS from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 about two months ago.

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54` means that line 40 and line 54 match in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Comment: You have many duplicate lines in the sources.list . Remove them.

Comment: As I stated in my question, I have checked the file and there are no duplicates.

Comment: @Terrance - you are right. I took a second look and found that the lines were identical. I think the initial confusion was that there was a comment at the end of line 54, so I didn't pick that. Thanks.